# Forming an Oracle SQL WHERE statement to include all results when they enter 'ALL' or only the criteria that they enter

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, parameters

Thank you in advance for any help!

I am having difficulty writing a where statement for an SSRS report I am writing. What I would like to do is have a parameter for 'Sites', for example, but allow the user to either enter in specific site numbers(which can include letters) or enter 'ALL' to just return all results.

What I have tried is:

```
((Case 
  WHEN (Upper(:Site) = 'ALL') THEN ('1')
  WHEN ((Upper(:Site) != 'ALL') 
  AND (SITE_NUMBER IN Upper(:Site))) THEN '1'
  ELSE '0' 
  END) = '1')
```

and

```
  ((Case 
  WHEN LENGTH(:Site) = 3 THEN ('1')
  WHEN (LENGTH(:Site) <> 3 
  AND (SITE_NUMBER IN (:Site))) THEN '1'
  ELSE '0' 
  END) = '1')
```

(The issue with the second one is that sometimes my value may be 3 digits)

What I have found is that these both seem to work until I enter multiple values in for :Site. If I do that I get ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments.

Normally I would just do a NVL qualifier but SSRS does not allow a parameter to both allow multiple values and allow NULL values.

I also thought about just doing a row visibility expression on my report but I need to do this for about 10 parameters so I don't think that is a feasible option.

Thanks again for any thoughts you may have!

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple boolean expression?

```
where (upper(:Site) = 'ALL' or site_number = upper(:site))
```

Comment: This does seem a lot simpler of an option however I don't seem to be able to put in multiple values and still have the = 'ALL' portion work. I get an invalid relational operator.  Thank you for the fast response though!

Comment: @CGreen . . . You would just use the same idea with `AND`/`OR` between the expressions.  If that doesn't make sense, you might want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try the following `WHERE` clause:

```
CASE
        WHEN UPPER(':Site') = 'ALL' THEN '1'
        WHEN SITE_NUMBER IN (
            SELECT
                REGEXP_SUBSTR('Site', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
            FROM
                DUAL
            CONNECT BY
                REGEXP_SUBSTR('Site', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
        ) THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END = '1'
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you Tejash. I had never tried the REGEXP_SUBSTR function. I am assuming with this code I am supposed to substitute my parameter in for 'Site'. When I do this and run it in sql developer it only pulls results for the first site that I enter in as a value for my parameter. When I try it in SSRS I am still getting the 'invalid number of arguments' error. Any thoughts? Once again this works for a single value and for a value of 'ALL'. Thanks again for the response!